# Ignore changes in folder in tortoise SVN

Tags: php, svn

I have folder named `temp` and there are some files, dynamically created with PHP system and at a midnight they are removed by CRON.

But, when I do something with my project, there will be some files and when I complete my work, then I want to commit changes but not files in this folder. Reason: it may (and will) cause errors on other computers, where is the same project.

I tried to add this folder to `ignore list` from context menu, but whoever will update to latest version of project, his `temp` will be removed. How can I prevent from this?

Comment: Just adding something to the ignore list won't delete anything, on your or anyone else's computer. Is this folder already versioned or something?

Comment: For example, when you are gong to checkout project, there will be no 'temp' folder. Also commit/merge/update will flag it as 'deleted' folder.

Comment: Then someone already added the folder to svn, and you were deleting it rather than just ignoring it. Now, you said these files are auto generated. Why does deleting the folder present a problem? Are *all* files in this folder auto generated? Is it ok to delete all the files if you leave the directory in place?

Comment: All files in folder are genereted automaticaly. But I already find a solution, when someone did some chagnes, he will test it and while testing, system will automaticaly remove all files in this folder, so commits will look like I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Since all files in the folder are auto-generated, I recommend leaving the folder itself, but using `svn rm` on any files *within* the folder. Then, set the `svn:ignore` property on the temp folder itself to "*". This will ignore all files within the folder so they do not get added back in.